# Managing Action Controller Parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this parameters:

```
 Parameters: {
"diagram"=>{"name"=>"name123"}, 
"isit"=>{
"0"=>{"xposition"=>"171", "yposition"=>"451", "titleid"=>"isit0", "description"=>"-description-", "leftrelationsids"=>"", "rightrelationsids"=>""}, 
"1"=>{"xposition"=>"254", "yposition"=>"554", "titleid"=>"isit1", "description"=>"-description-", "leftrelationsids"=>"", "rightrelationsids"=>""}}}
```

In the create method that receives the parameters above I want to store a diagram (that for now it it just the name of it) and after that I want to store each of the components.

I'm doing this in the `diagrams_controller.rb`create method. The diagram has_many components.

My problem is how to store the components data?

I have tried this (for now just tried to of the columns, xposition and yposition):

```
def create
  @diagram = Diagram.new(diagram_params)
  @diagram.save

  @diagram.components.create(params.require(:isit).permit(:xposition, :yposition))
```

The diagram are stored, but the components not. I don't know how to handle this require permite thing to the components.

Here is the result:

[image]

Any help? How should I store the components?

Comment: Don't use a screen shot to show us data, code, or output, especially when that image is so small it's not readable. Doing so wastes the time of those who are trying to help you.

Comment: Sorry for that! I did not realize at first that it was not as readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this code:

```
@diagram = Diagram.new(diagram_params)
@diagram.save
component = Component.create(params.require(:isit).permit(:xposition, :yposition))
@diagram.components << component
@diagram.save
```

Or use `accepts_nested_attributes_for` in diagram model, and edit `diagram_params` method to add the following:

```
params.require(:diagram).permit(components_attributes: [:xposition, :yposition])
```

Read about [accepts_nested_attributes_for](http://blog.biasedwalk.com/2013/06/acceptsnestedattributesfor-on-hasmany.html)